# FunctionDomain and FunctionRange for x^2/x returns "True"

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

I'm very concerned. As far as I know, the output should be:

$x < 0\ ||\ x> 0$

$y < 0\ ||\ y> 0$

[image: the code]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that

```
g[x]
```

returns

> `x`

So, when you write

```
FunctionDomain[g[x], x, Reals]
```

it is really writing

```
FunctionDomain[x, x, Reals]
```

On way to bypass, is to `Hold` like so:

```
FunctionDomain[Hold[x^2/x], x, Reals]
FunctionRange[Hold[x^2/x], x, y, Reals]
```

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! But is there a way to pass a variable or a function that contains the expression and get the correct result?

Comment: @AndreyLeshchev-Romanenko I guess you could do something like: `g[x_] := x^2/x // Hold` and then `FunctionDomain[g[x], x, Reals]` but I am not sure how satisfactory that is for your purposes

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what I need for now. Thank you!

Comment: @AndreyLeshchev-Romanenko glad I was able to help :-)